# How to extract a numeric value before specific word in dataset

Tags: r

My dataset was created with an OCR routine. Its already converted as a dataset

```
V1    V2      V3    V4      V5    V6       V7 
AAA   BBB     CCC   DDD     7784  ORIGEN   EEE
AAA   BBB     5524  ORIGEN  CCC   DDD      EEE
AAA   BBB     CCC   DDD     EEE   9888     ORIGEN
1234" ORIGEN  AAA   BBB     CCC   DDD      EEE
```

Im looking to extract the value immediately before ORIGEN. Its always a 4-digit number but due to the OCR, sometimes it comes with a extra special character (* or ")

```
X1
7784  
5524
9888
1234"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `max.col` to get the index of columns in each row where the 'ORIGEN' string occurs, subtract 1 from it, `cbind` with the sequence of rows and extract the corresponding value

```
out <- data.frame(X1 = as.numeric(df1[cbind(seq_len(nrow(df1)), 
            max.col(df1 == 'ORIGEN', 'first') -1)]))
```

-output

```
out
#    X1
#1 7784
#2 5524
#3 9888
#4 1234
```

---

If we need a partial match, use `grep`

```
data.frame(X1 = as.numeric(apply(df1, 1, function(x) x[grep(".*ORIGEN", x)-1])))
```

-output

```
#  X1
#1 7784
#2 5524
#3 9888
#4 1234
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(V1 = c("AAA", "AAA", "AAA", "1234"), V2 = c("BBB", 
"BBB", "BBB", "ORIGEN"), V3 = c("CCC", "5524", "CCC", "AAA"), 
    V4 = c("DDD", "ORIGEN", "DDD", "BBB"), V5 = c("7784", "CCC", 
    "EEE", "CCC"), V6 = c("ORIGEN", "DDD", "9888", "DDD"), V7 = c("EEE", 
    "EEE", "ORIGEN", "EEE")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: thanks. as a follow up, what if sometimes the word ORIGEN comes with an special character? for example `¿ORIGEN`
is it possible to run a parcial match?

Comment: @AndresMora I already updated wiht `grep`.

Comment: thanks. can the `.*` be used for partial matches both sides? `grep(".*ORIGEN.*", x)`

Comment: @AndresMora yes you can do that, but it is not necessary as the code I showed should match those cases as well

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
a <- df1=="ORIGEN"
df1[a[,c(2:ncol(a),1)]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
apply(df1,1,function(x)lag(x)[x=="ORIGEN"])
```